# How to get the size in bytes or KB from javascript fetch API that would match the same call from postman?

Tags: javascript, http, postman, fetch-api

In postman if I make a call, I see that the size from the return data shows 1.64KB. This is from the area beside the status and time. I assume this includes headers and other things.

From a javascript perspective, I am making the same exact call using fetch api, however if take the body string and calculate the size in bytes like this (this is a bit of vue.js code, but ignore that):

```
const CallSize = computed(() => {
  const byteSize = new Blob([api_call_result.value]).size;
  return byteSize;
});
```

I am getting something smaller like 63 bytes.

How can I calculate it to match what postman gets?

Thanks

Comment: Are the response headers counted? What about encoding? chunked/gzip...

Comment: I am not sure. From the response from fetch API, is there a way to calculate recieved payload size?